# Value from js to JSP [MDM IBM]

Tags: javascript, jsp, mdm

Hi I'm working on MDM CE of IBM.

I'm working on an entry preview script.

I have a list of item displayed on screen and i took with JS those one that are checked in checkbox.

Obviously JSP code can't use it those value. How can I send these information to JSP and maybe got it back after the server response ?

I know that i can work with ajax but i actually can't on the MDM product.

Comment: I don't know MDM but if you can't use Ajax or an equivalent, an old school solution is to pass the values as parameters of the JSP. This force you to reload the page each time you need to do what you want to do.

Comment: Can't do that for security problem. Must stay on the same page and can't reload it self.